# Regex to strip outer HTML tags in string

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I need a regex to strip outer/top level HTML tags in a string but keep the internal ones.

```
$str = "<div>Start <br /> <span>test</span> end.</div>";
```

Into

```
$str = "Start <br /> <span>test</span> end.";
```

As well as

```
$str = "<aside id="main" class="one">Start <br /> <span>test</span> end.</aside>";
```

Into

```
$str = "Start <br /> <span>test</span> end.";
```

.

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $str);
```

Removes all tags not just outer ones.

Comment: Better to use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) than a hacky regexp

Comment: DOM cannot select contents of the tag without stripping tags that present in content. 
It can however select entire tag with contents like  `<div>bla <br> bla</div>` and now i just need to strip the actual outer tag (div in this case) and keep the content with tags.

Comment: `$html = $domElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML($domElement);` should return the content of the Dom node in $html without stripping the tags within it

Comment: The question is not if DOM is better than regex, but how to do it with a regex... There are valid reasons to use regex instead of DOM, one major adavantage of regex is much faster performance than DOM (see here http://blog.futtta.be/2014/05/01/php-html-parsing-performance-shootout-regex-vs-dom/)

Comment: 1000 views, and only a downvote. Bravo SO, this place used to be positive. What happened? no answer, just some people thinking highly of themselves

Answer (score 4):

**Please note**

Using a regex is not the best way to modify HTML code!
In most situations it is better and much more reliable to use a DOMDocument or DOMDocumentFragement object to modify or extract data from HTML code.

However, there are valid scenarios where a regex is better, mainly when these factors apply:

- You know that the HTML code that you edit is going to be valid.
- The HTML structure that is modified will be identical in all cases.
- You're doing only very simple changes to the code.
- Performance is important (e.g. when it is executed inside a loop). *DOMDocument is considerably slower than a simple regex!*

**The code**

To strip the outermost tag from some HTML code use this regex:

```
/* Note: 
 * The code must start with an opening tag and end with a closing tag. 
 * No white space or other text must be present before the first 
 * tag/after the last tag, else you get some unexpected results.
 */

$contents = preg_replace( '/^<[^>]+>|<\/[^>]+>$/', '', $markup );
            // ^<[^>]+>     This removes the first tag
            // <\/[^>]+>$   This removes the last closing tag
```

**Examples**

This regex works for most HTML markup e.g.

```
In: '<div class="my-text" id="text" style="color:red">some text</div>'
Out: 'some text' (expected result)
```

When the first tag contains the ">" character it's going to break everything, e.g.

```
In: '<div title="Home > Archives">Archive overview</div>'
Out: ' Archives">Archive overview' (unexpected result)
```

Also whitespace/text in the start or end will break the regex

```
In: '<div>Your name</div>:'
Out: 'Your name</div>:' (unexpected result)
```

And of course, any tag will be stripped, without any sanity check, e.g.

```
In: '<h2>Settings</h2><label>Page Title</label>'
Out: 'Settings</h2><label>Page Title' (unexpected result)
```

Answer (score 2):

How to take a DOM element, and simulate `innerHTML()`

```
$html = '<html><body><div><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul></div></body></html>';

function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element) { 
    $innerHTML = "";
    foreach ($element->childNodes as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }

    return $innerHTML; 
} 

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $child) {
    $html = DOMinnerHTML($child); 
    echo $html, PHP_EOL;
}
```

without having to resort to regexp

Comment: Any way to do this without knowing the parent tagname?

Answer (score 0):

This basic regex will probably do. It does not, however, account for tags that have attributes that contain `>`s, and thus will trip.

```
Find: <[^>]*>([\s\S]*)<\/[^>]*>
Replace: $1
```

It gets more complex if you expect attributes may contain tag brackets.

```
Find: <(?:[^>]*?(?:(?:"[^"]*?"|'[^']*?')+[^>]*?)|[\s\S]*?)>([\s\S]*)<\/[^>]*>
Replace: $1
```

Either one should do the trick.

Comment: Getting error `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']'` on first regex.

Comment: @RomanToasov Try escaping the forward slash. `<[^>]*>([\s\S]*)<\/[^>]*>`

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that removes the HTML tags along with their contents:

Function:

```
<?php
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE) {
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    else {
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
  }
  elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
  }
  return $text;
}
?>
```

Sample text:
$text = '**sample** text with tags';

Result for strip_tags($text):
sample text with tags

Result for strip_tags_content($text):
text with

Result for strip_tags_content($text, '**'):
sample** text with

Result for strip_tags_content($text, '', TRUE);
text with tags

I hope that someone is useful :)